# Decompose the schema to BCNF with algorithm

Tags: bcnf

Does the following steps be correct?

```
R = (P, N, O, C, E)

N -> P

E -> P

O -> C

O -> P
```

In the relation above, we can see that there are two violations. N -> P and E -> P is a many-to-one relation and O -> C and O -> P is a one-to-many relation. That means, for 1 value of X, 2 values of Y exist. The relations can be rewritten as NE -> P and O -> CP.

First of all, we calculate the attribute closure for the given relation. And using attribute closure, we will find the candidate key for the relation. For R to be in BCNF, if X -> Y holds true in R, the X must be super-key of R.

```
P+ = P
N+ = NP
O+ = OCP
C+ = C
E+ = EP
NEO+ = NEOCP
```

So, the candidate key (minimal super key) is NEO. Now we start the algorithm.
For the relation, NE -> P

S = {N, E, O, C, P}
S = {NE, OCP}, because of the functional dependency, NE ->P, which violated BCNF. Thus, we dissolve the relation into two relations.
S = {NE, OC, OP} because of the functional dependency, O -> CP, which violated BCNF. Now, we have 3 relations that are in BCNF form.

Comment: What part of this process do you think is in error, and why?

Comment: Im confusing that NE->P and O->CP are or are not violations. Is that because of the 1NF rule which requires value has to be atomic? Therefore, it can't be BCNF before the decomposition.